# How can I print a find('all',$params) query in browser output in cakephp2.x?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
$params = array(
    'fields' => array(          
        'OutCountry,Sum(TotalCalls),Sum(ConnectedCalls),sum(Duration),(Sum(ConnectedCalls)/Sum(TotalCalls))*100,sum(Duration)/Sum(ConnectedCalls),
    sum(SaleAmount) as SaleAmount'),
    'table'=> 'Nextone_cdr_reports.'.$tabname ,
    'conditions'=>array(
        'InDate' => date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 days")),'not'=>array('OutCountry'=>null)),
    'group' => 'OutCountry',
    'order' => $orderby
);

$rs = $this->find('all',$params);
```

I want to make it print in Model only.How Can I do so?

Comment: Please, provide code formatting and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To print your query in cakephp 2.x Please follow these step

1)set the debug variable to 2 in app/config/config.php

2) `<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump');?>`
at the end of your layout. This should actually be commented out in your default cake layout.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to print the result of this query?
If yes then you can print the result of this query using below code in your model file.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rs);
exit();
```